# What is the term for a hedge-covered pathway?

Tags: phrase-requests

I was in Port Isaac, Cornwall, a few years ago, and found this path (see link to photos, below) that seemed to go right up inside a cultivated hedge or tree-line between two pastures. Does anyone know the proper word or phrase for this kind of covered pathway? Thank you!

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3099726590360&set=a.3099723150274.1073741824.1780044023&type=3&theater

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3099726590360&set=a.3099723150274.1073741824.1780044023&type=3&theater

Comment: This is a dead link or it requires privileges to view.

Comment: Facebook links are not usually reliable as the site does require logins.

Comment: Was it a colonnade of trees? https://www.google.com/search?q=colonnade+of+trees&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYmuXB5IXSAhVLjlQKHeKrC3AQsAQIJA&biw=1596&bih=787

Comment: The landscaping term for a path that has trees or shrubs surrounding it is an [Avenue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avenue_(landscape))

Comment: Another possibility is a [pergola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pergola), though this usually refers to a wooden structure covered in vines rather than something carved out of the trees.

Comment: If you don't want to post the actual picture, you can do a Google Image search for a similar photo. When you have the picture open in your browser, right click on it (or whatever the Mac equivalent of right-clicking is) and one of the options will be "Search Google for image". One of the options that comes up in your Google search results will be "Visually similar images" which may lead you to a photo you can share here.

Answer (score 6):

It is called a ***pleached tunnel*** or a ***pleached allee***.  See [Gardening Knowhow](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/trees/tgen/what-is-pleaching.htm), article titled *What Is Pleaching: Tips On Pleaching Hedges And Trees*.  See also [Images for Pleached Tunnel](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pleached+tunnel&biw=1105&bih=648&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivitaivIbSAhXLOyYKHY7oBUQQsAQILw).

[image]

Landscape Architects Network. Photo credit: Pleached allee, Glen Burnie Historic Home ... Architectural Photographer: Ron Blunt  (ronbluntphoto.com)

The article is an introduction on how to pleach trees. It starts:

> Pleached trees, also called espaliered trees, are used to create
>   arbors, tunnels and arches as well as the “hedge on stilts” look.

The article concludes:

> Arbors and tunnels retain the framework permanently. If you are
>   creating a pleached tunnel, be sure it is tall enough that you will be
>   able to pass through it once the pleaching technique spreads the
>   branches onto the support.

Comment: Don't forget the correct attribution of photographer and site for the image.

Comment: I've added the picture, but with Andrew Leach's reminder, rolled it back since it appears to come from a commercial photographer, albeit via Pinterest. The link remains in the edit log, so you can roll it back and add the required information.

Comment: How to insert the picture: click the "Images" link you provided, click the thumbnail, then click the "View image" button to get a URL that ends with "jpg". Copy the URL from the browser's address bar. [Edit] your post, select the "Image" tool (or press Ctrl+G), click "link from the web" under the main box, and paste the URL you just copied.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Comment: If you don't mind my asking: your profile says "Close account"; you're not leaving EL&U, are you?

Comment: @Lawrence No, that must have been leftover from when I merged an account I had as an unregistered user at Science F&F, although why it appeared here on ELU is a puzzlement.  I deleted the entry.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Phew, I'm glad you're sticking around. :)

Answer (score 4):

[**Arborway**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arborway): *an arbored passage or walk.*

[**Arbor**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arbor): *a shelter of vines or branches or of latticework covered with climbing shrubs or vines.*